# How to apply the asp.net authorization in two different folders?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

[image]

I have two folders in my asp.net website namely VENDORS and ADMIN

i want when any user access any of the page inside the ADMIN folder it redirects to Admin/login.aspx until they login ....

i want when any user access any of the page inside the VENDORS folder it redirects to Vendors/login.aspx until they login ....

How to do that using web.config authorization ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have web.config files inside the admin and vendors folder separately. Inside these web.config files you would declare your `<formsauthentication>` elements independently. The global web.config should contain no `<formsauthentication>` element.

**Edit:**
I will provide a xml snippet below, but implementing FormsAuthentication is not a task I would recommend for someone who is a beginner. First you should read and understand the process involved in implementing at least a [basic FormsAuthentication model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx). That being said, this would be the relevant web.config entry under the `<system.web>` section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/vendors/login.aspx" 
           protection="All" 
           timeout="30" 
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           requireSSL="false" 
           slidingExpiration="false" 
           defaultUrl="~/vendors/default.aspx" 
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: You will probably want to identify the authorization roles in each case as well.

Comment: @mellamokb - If OP was using a common formsauthentication architecture I would recommend the usage of roles, but unless he has different levels of vendors or different levels of administrators, the separation of authentication responsibility really makes roles fairly irrelevant. My recommendation to OP would be to use a common authentication framework and use roles as you suggest, but I've answered the question "as is".

Comment: @user594849 - I've answered the question "as is". Are you asking what would be the ideal way to design this separation of areas or are you looking for a snippet regarding specifically the answer I gave?

Comment: ya i want the code snippet sample ..how to do this ..because i m the beginner ...

Comment: @user594849 - Code snippet provided in edit, but I recommend you read the link I provided as well. It has valuable background information on this process.

Comment: @Joel, I know this is a bit old but your suggestion is incorrect "You need to have web.config files inside the admin and vendors folder separately. Inside these web.config files you would declare your <formsauthentication> elements independently." The <authentication> element can only be in the web.config file which is in the website's root folder. Trying to put this element in a web.config file stored in a subfolder will generate this asp.net error "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level."

Comment: @Anthony: As I've gotten this model to work on several sites, I'm pretty sure I'm not incorrect. However, this answer doesn't go into all of the details necessary to make it work "out of the box".

Comment: @Joel, do you mind checking it? I would be interested in your solution: "You need to have web.config files inside the admin and vendors folder separately. Inside these web.config files you would declare your <formsauthentication> elements independently. The global web.config should contain no <formsauthentication> element." but I can't get it to work and from what I've read the <authentication> element can only be in the web.config file which is in the website's root folder. If it does work I prefer your solution so do you mind explaining what you did exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the vendor and admin site are completely unrelated, I would recommend having a single authentication architecture.  Have a login page at the root level, then use `<location>` elements to define role authorization (or separate `web.config` files in each subfolder).  Is it absolutely necessary that administrators login to `/admin/login.aspx` and vendors login to `/vendors/login.aspx`?

Comment: Look it up.  There's lots of documentation out there on `web.config`, `<location>`, `<formsauthentication>`, and creating login pages.  Plan how you will lay out your site, do what you can, then come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @user594849 - There really is no "code snippet" for this. This answer is a recommendation of an architecture. This will really require the reading and understanding of the documentation regarding FormsAuthentication.