# How to use the multiple login for multiple folders using web.config?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config, forms-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply the asp.net authorization in two different folders ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043626/how-to-apply-the-asp-net-authorization-in-two-different-folders)

How to use the multiple login for multiple folders ?
[image]

i have two different login pags in folders ADMIn and VEndors ...i want when any of the user directly access any of the page inside admin folder then it redirect to login page of Admin folder ......

and if any of the user directly access any of the page inside Vendors folder then it redirect to login page of Vendors folder ......

Comment: You already asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043626/how-to-apply-the-asp-net-authorization-in-two-different-folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work - you would need to mark both folders as separate, isolated Web Applications in order to have two different login configurations. This is because to specify different login pages, you'd need a web.config in each of those subfolders. If you tried this, you'd see that trying to change the login page is not allowed as the Web Application starts at /.

Instead, consider putting a single login page in the root and in the page, examine the redirectUrl parameter to see which page the user clicked on and change your theme (or whatever it is you're trying to do) accordingly.

If you're trying to keep two separate groups of users and authentication sources, then you will have to split those two subfolders as separate web applications, as previously mentioned.

-Oisin