# How To Have Multiple Login Page Styles In ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My site will have a few tools/sub-sites available for people to do different things.  I have one common Login UserControl that will be used so I am not really duplicating much.  But each of these sub-sites have their own MasterPage and thus styling.  There is only one User table in the database and there are Roles for which sub-site you can get to.  The Login UserControl will handle that.

Here is a simplized folder structure:

\Root

--> Images

--> Scripts

--> Styles

--> POHR

------> Login.aspx

------> PORHMasterPage

--> Beer

------> Login.aspx

------> BeerMasterPage

--> StatusUpdates

------> Login.aspx

------> StatusUpdatesMasterPage

Each of those Login Pages use the same Login UserControl which validates people and sets up a Cookie as see here:

```
public void LogUserIn(string EMailOrName, string Password) {
  DS.User u = DS.Common.ValidateUser(EMailOrName, Password);

  if (u != null) {
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
      1,
      u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
      DateTime.UtcNow,
      DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
      true,
      string.Format("UserID={0}|SiteID={1}", u.ID, SiteID)
    );
    string eTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, eTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(EMailOrName, true);
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
  } // if they got authenticated
} // LogUserIn - Method
```

My issue is the FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl.  It is returning /default.aspx.  I tried adding the following to the Web.config

```
<location path="~/StatusUpdates">
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/StatusUpdates/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/StatusUpdates/Dashboard.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="false" name="MGG_StatusUpdates" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="~/Beer">
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Beer/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Beer/Dashboard.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="false" name="MGG_Beer" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I would expect a page the above defaultUrl values to be passed back based on where I am in the application.

My questions are... How can I get this to do what I want?  Do I need Web.config files in each of those folders, if so, what should they hold as well as what should the root's web.config file have.

Comment: I have gone through and Accepted the items that I had not Accepted an answer to.  Now granted, some have no answers.  So of the ones with answers, I am 100% accepted.

Comment: Why have multiple logins ? why not just have permissions ?

Comment: There are NOT Multiple Logins for people.  It is a Single login record and yes, the users have Permissions on which site(s) they can get to and what they can do in each.  There are only multiple login pages that reference the same single login UserControl simply so each login can be styled with its own MasterPage.

Comment: So do you want to have dynamically loading CSS ? for the different styles ?

Comment: No.  They Styling is all taken care of by the MasterPages.  What I am asking is how do I get the FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl to return the appropriate page.  It is always returning /default.aspx.  If that means a web.config in each folder then show or point me how.  if I need to change something in the root's web.config show or point me how.  I am not sure why the defaultUrl attribute shown above is not doing the trick.

Comment: Looks like this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043626/how-to-apply-the-asp-net-authorization-in-two-different-folders